# I cannot go to http://novathon.cloud.reply.eu/wp-admin - always redirected to /wp-login

Tags: wp-admin, redirect

I need to login as admin, and I know the credentials, but I am always redireceted to login page. Why is this hapening, and how I can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the redirect URL is the same as the login one. Sometimes, if the domain doesn't have www and you had navigated before to that url, the browser remembers the old url.

http://**novathon.cloud.reply.eu**/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2F**www.novathon.cloud.reply.eu**%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Both Urls must be the same.